# CosmosDB (Mongo) - Can't convert from object to date

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have some data in a Cosmos MongoDB instance that looks like the following :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("64d4d976cbfc54f15ab14067"),
  "user" : "user@domain.com",
  "date" : {
      "$date" : "2022-10-10T10:34:07Z"
   }
}
```

I am not really sure why this conversion happens when the date field that has been submitted was in milliseconds since last epoch as in : 1665398047000.

The date field was generated from a javascript POST request  :

```
data = new FormData()
..
data.append("date", Date.now())
```

On the server side, the corresponding data schema is :

```
const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  ...
  date: Date,
  ...
});
```

And this is where the POST route registers the data to the DB :

```
 var data = new Data({
  user: req.body.User,
  ...
  date: req.body.date,
})
```

I want to group the results by year, using an aggregate filter (stripped away unnecessary parts) :

```
{
{
  $group: {
    _id: { $year: "$date"} 

},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
  }
},
{
  $sort: { _id: 1 },
}
}
```

This would result in the following error :

```
MongoServerError: Can't convert from object to date
at Connection.onMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:207:30)
at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:60:60)
at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
at processIncomingData (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20)
at MessageStream._write (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:391:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:332:10)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:336:10)
at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the following steps to convert from object to date:**

- The `connectAndRun()` function is designed to connect to the **MongoDB** server using the supplied connection string.
- It updates a document in the specified collection with the current date and time in the ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`.
- `updateOne()` method is used to perform the update operation in this case, based on the **_id** field.
- Using the `connectAndRun()` function, the connection to the database is established, the document is updated, and any potential issues are handled.

**Code I tried with:**

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = '*****';
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function connectAndRun() {
  try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Connected to the database');
        const db = client.db('newDb'); 
        const collection = db.collection('newColl'); 

        const filter = { _id:  '1' }; 
        const currentDate = new  Date();
        const formattedDate = currentDate.toISOString();

        const update = {
            $set: {lastUpdated : formattedDate }
        };

  try {
        const result = await  collection.updateOne(filter, update);
        console.log('Document updated successfully:', result.modifiedCount, 'document(s) modified');
  } 
  catch (err) 
  {
    console.error('Error updating document:', err);
  }

} 
 catch (err) 
{
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
} 
finally {
    client.close();
  }
}
connectAndRun();
```

**Input:**

- Data stored in [DB](https://i.imgur.com/858UtEO.png).

**Output:**

- Output in [Console](https://i.imgur.com/K20dRVE.png).
- Data in DB after converting from object to [date](https://i.imgur.com/LcFXZFW.png).

Comment: Please... *please*... stop posting screen caps of text - they are literally a problem, for many reasons. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Everything in your output could have been formatted text, with none of the inherent issues with images of text.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Removed screen caps from the answer.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I meant... copy the text that you're trying to show, and post it to your question as properly-formatted text instead of a screenshot (just like you shared your code as text). Making the images clickable links doesn't fix the problem (and now adds an extra step for people, as they will inevitably click each link). Just post formatted JSON for the data, and post formatted console text.